# IoT Edge integrated VS Code commands not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-iot-edge

I run into issue, that Visual Studio Code is displaying error when trying to run whatever IoT-Edge command. It is not possible to build and push image for instance or call any other IoT Edge command. Please what may be the issue? The IoT Edge extension is of course installed.

Comment: Hi, could you help paste the detailed error messages or screenshots?

Comment: Have your installed Docker and Docker Support for Visual Studio Code based on [the document](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsciot-vscode.azure-iot-edge)?

Comment: Hi, I have Docker and Docker for VSCode installed. I am capable to run the build and push steps manually, but would be great to be capable to use VS Code support for that. When I right click module.json file and try to build image thru context menu, simply nothing happens. No dialog is opened. When I try to open command window and type >Azure-IoT-Edge some command I am getting error that command does not exist, however autocomplete in command windows offers me it as a option. Here is the screenshot of only error that I receive:  http://i64.tinypic.com/29yny1y.png Thanks

Comment: Please try to uninstall these 3 extensions: Azure Account, Azure IoT Toolkit and Azure IoT Edge. Then try installing the Azure IoT Edge extension again

Comment: Tried, now I am not able to get the IoT Edge extension back. Already tried to reinstall VS Code. Please how can I get rid of all the files related to VS Code, so I can do clean installation. Apparently, when checking delete everything checkbox during uninstall is not deleting everything....

Comment: Please try to re-install IoT Edge extension, not the VS Code itself. Refer to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_uninstall-an-extension

Comment: Hi @JunHan I tried, but VS Code got stuck and it won't install the extension back. That is why I want to do full wipe out of VS Code.

Comment: @marek_lani  Try installing the insider version of VS Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/

Comment: I still have a problem with 'build and push'. Works up until push where it complains it need authorization. Manual docker push works fine using values from .env [2c]